# Can I drag in extra Maven dependencies for different WAR plugin executions

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a pom that is supposed to build 2 different WARs (one will add a classifier). I can have 2 `<execution>` blocks in the WAR plugin configurations and this works fine, but I need to drag in different dependencies between the executions.

For example, the first execution would build the default WAR containing the modern libs, and the other would build a legacy-compatible WAR using old libs. This would mean the dependencies would differ between the WAR plugin executions. Is this achievable?

The end goal is to produce both WARs in one go. I know this sounds counter-Maven, but why would the WAR plugin allow multiple executions if not to support similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the biggest problem with having a single artefact ID produce multiple artefacts is addressing the artefacts. Most notably - declaring the artefacts as dependencies to other projects.

Why not simply create two different projects with the artefact IDs clearly stating whether legacy libraries are used?

[Relevant article](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.VBfnSa1OA1w)